# Magento shopping cart front end went to text only with an Error and a Fatal Error on the Admin login page

Tags: fatal-error, 404-page

I am working on [www.5280flowers.com](http://www.5280flowers.com) website.

The Base URL and Base Skin Url are set correctly.

```
    web/unsecure/base_url --> http: //www. 5280flowers.com/ 
    web/secure/base_url --) https: //www. 5280flowers.com/ web/unsecure/base_skin_url --) 

{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/======web/secure/base_skin_url --) {{secure_base_url}}skin/
```

There has been absolutely no changes done to the shopping cart and it worked fine about 3 hours ago....Now - it only loads text on the front page with the following Error:

There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.

And - when I go to the Admin login page it shows (all text - no images):

Log in to Admin Panel

User Name:

Password:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/MYownSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php
>   on line 43

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: can you please post URL where you are getting this error?

Comment: Can I send it to you privately?

Comment: www.5280flowers.com

Comment: Have you changed any thing in System >> Manage Stores section or in System >> Configuration >> Web section?

Comment: I didn't touch it at all...

Comment: I am 99% sure that Base URL or Base Skin Url is wrong.

Comment: it seems that the Base URL and Base Skin Url are set correctly...web/unsecure/base_url --> http: //www. 5280flowers.com/ ======web/secure/base_url --) https: //www. 5280flowers.com/ ======web/unsecure/base_skin_url --) {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/======web/secure/base_skin_url --) {{secure_base_url}}skin/

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following in core_config_data table in database:

Value of:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url

web/unsecure/base_skin_url
web/secure/base_skin_url
```

If still every thing does not go fine, then you need to check file system permission also.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url --> http: //www. 5280flowers.com/

Comment: web/secure/base_url  --) https: //www. 5280flowers.com/

Comment: web/unsecure/base_skin_url --) {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

Comment: web/secure/base_skin_url --) {{secure_base_url}}skin/

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was an issue with Cache! (is that possible?) At least that's what the Shopgate people said after the poked around in there....Renaming the Cache seemed to fix the problem...I don't really understand this but OK...

Comment: Ah.. ok. How can I forget that magento has big problem of caching :)